# Jira transition in Python

Tags: python, jira, jira-rest-api

I created a simple python application that creates tasks in Jira

some code leak below:

```
if response.status_code == 201:
        issue_key = response.json()["key"]
        result_label.config(text=f"Task '{summary}' created successfully!\nIssue key: {issue_key}")
       #go to in progress
        if transition_jira_issue(issue_key, "11", username, password):
          #go to closed
            if transition_jira_issue(issue_key, "21", username, password):
                result_label.config(text=f"Task '{summary}' transitioned to 'Closed' successfully!")
            else:
                result_label.config(text=f"Failed to transition the task '{summary}' to 'Closed'.")
        else:
            result_label.config(text=f"Failed to transition the task '{summary}' to 'In Progress'.")
    else:
        result_label.config(text=f"Failed to create the task '{summary}'.\nResponse: {response.text}")


def transition_jira_issue(issue_key, transition_id, username, password):
   
    payload = {
        "transition": {
            "id": transition_id
        }
    }
    
    json_payload = json.dumps(payload)

   
    response = requests.post(f"{api_url}/{issue_key}/transitions", verify=False, auth=(username, password),
                             headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"}, data=json_payload)
```

in my jira board:
transition to in progress has id: 11,
transition to closed has id: 21

Unfortunately after running the code the task goes to in progress but not to closed.
If I want to drag it manually in the Kanban board, I also have to mark 'complete' in resolution. I don't know how to handle this in code. That's probably why id '21' doesn't work
[resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDFHq.png)

Comment: Edit your Jira Workflow to automatically fill the Resolution field when it is transitioned to Closed. The transition is likely blocked because of an empty resolution field or some other condition.